# ASP.NET Page with around 200 controls taking time to load

Tags: asp.net, performance

I have an issue loading the form.It takes around 15 sec to load in IE8. Is there any way where i can show first 50 controls and loading aother controls at back ground so that user has access to first 50 controls which are loaded while remaining are loading to come on screen
Can any one please help me on this?

Thanks,
Suraj

Comment: Can you output cache the page?

Comment: What kind of controls are they ? Please give us a url, or some kind of part of the page. Where is the delay come from, do you know ? Maybe you need to consider a better design of your page ?

Answer (score 1):

To send a part of your page you use the `Flush()` some where inside your page, eg:

```
...html code...
<%Response.Flush();%>
...rest of html code...
```

but if the delay is on code behind, eg on query your database, then the flush is not help at that point and you also need to move some of your calculations (if this is possible) right after the `flush()` eg:

```
...html code...
<%
 Response.Flush(); 
 // Call CodeBehind Function that takes some time
 MoreCalculations();
 %>
...rest of html code...
```

Comment: This is a good idea. Also you can look into multiview to split your form, or ajax to do partial loading.

Comment: @SutharMonil Yes of course there are some more tricks. I just right something to start with but I suspect that the issue is on bad design, is ask a lot of data together and with out cache.

Comment: I completely agree with your ideas. And yes 200 controls is really a lot to ask for on a aspx page. That is why i am suggesting partial loading ir creating multiviews. Sometimes, the requirement is such that you cant dodge such a situation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added Response.Flush(); method but the code above response.flush gets executed on the browser and then gives me the error for below code.the error is "Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent. "Why this happens?

Comment: @Suraj Because you try to send later headers commands. Header commands must be send on the start of the page not later. Now if you make flush is too later for header.

Comment: @Suraj With out see some code I can not help you more my friend.

Answer (score 0):

That is a large number of controls.

Your main problem here will be the `ViewState`. Take a look at your page size. It would be a few MB. Not a good design for the web.

Steps you can take:

1. Redesign your page to use fewer controls. You can use the session to maintain values and break you entry form into several smaller forms.
2. You can move the `ViewState` into session. This will give you some relief. Use the [`SessionPageStatePersister`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.sessionpagestatepersister.aspx) for this.
3. Set hidden controls to `Visible="False"`. Controls hidden via CSS or javascript are still rendered taking up bandwidth. Setting the contorls to `Visible="False"` tells the server not to render them. The drawback of this is that you have to PostBack to the server if you need them to be shown.
4. For controls that will not change for your page lifecycle, set the `ViewStateMode="Disabled"`. This will ensure that they don't write their contents to the ViewState.